# PDO Problem. Execute arguments not being read?

Tags: php

Here is my function to return the most popular videos. For some reason it don't acknowledge the :limit. If I remove ':limit' and implicitly put in the number 10 it works.

Method:

```
function getPopularVideos($limit) {
$dbc = connectToDatabase();
$q = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, :limit');
$q->execute(array(':limit' => $limit));
return $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Calling code:

```
$popularVideos = getPopularVideos(10);
```

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong. Little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#76966) this happens because the limit is being quoted, which wrecks the SQL syntax. The suggested workaround is using bindParam instead.